# How do you handle oncut, oncopy, and onpaste in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, webkit

The [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind#typedatafn) says the library has built-in support for the following events: blur, focus, load, resize, scroll, unload, click, dblclick, mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, mouseenter, mouseleave, change, select, submit, keydown, keypress, keyup, and error.

I need to handle cut, copy, and paste events. How best to do that? FWIW, I only need to worry about WebKit (lucky me!).

UPDATE: I'm working on a "widget" in a Dashboard-like environment. It uses WebKit, so it only really matters (for my purposes) whether these events are supported there, which it looks like they are.

Comment: In researching a bit for this answer, I found that IE has support for reading from the clipboard in JavaScript (!!) via `window.clipboardData`. Firefox doesn't, thankfully. I doubt Webkit does either, being sane. Are you sure that you really need to handle cut/copy/paste commands? Perhaps you are approaching the problem from the wrong perspective. If you edit your answer to provide the reason behind your request, perhaps I or someone else can give you more help.

Comment: So jQuery doesn't document partial support then, I mean for events such as paste and copy.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can add and remove events of any kind by using the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off) methods

Try this, for instance

```
jQuery(document).on('paste', function(e){ alert('pasting!') });
```

jQuery is actually quite indifferent to whether the event type you assign is supported by the browser, so you can assign arbitrary event types to elements (and general objects) such as:

```
jQuery('p').on('foobar2000', function(e){ alert(e.type); });
```

In case of custom event types, you must [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) them "manually" in your code, like this:

```
jQuery('p').trigger('foobar2000');
```

Neat eh?

Furthermore, to work with proprietary/custom DOM events in a cross-browser compatible way, you may need to use/write an "jQuery event plugin" ... example of which may be seen in <del>[jquery.event.wheel.js](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.event.wheel.js.txt)</del> Brandon Aaron's [Mousewheel plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel)

Comment: Broken links: `off` and `jquery.event.wheel.js`.

Comment: .off link is OK, and the jquery.event.wheel.js is marked `<del>`eted but left in for historical reasons.

Answer (score 14):

Various clipboard events are available in Javascript, though support is spotty. QuicksMode.org has a [compatibility grid](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html) and [test page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/cutcopypaste.html). The events are not exposed through jQuery, so you'll either have to extend the library or use native Javascript events.

Answer (score 9):

Mozilla supports an "input" event which I'm having trouble finding useful documentation for.  At the very least, I know it fires on paste.

```
   this.addEventListener('input',
    function(){//stuff here},
    false
   );
```

Comment: Thanks, Josh. This seems to work in FF and IE.
 
`$('#myinput').bind('input', function() { my_immediate_response_function();});`

Comment: Seems to work fine in FF, IE, Chrome and Safari! Super, thanks.

Comment: In IE 9, the input event doesn't fire if you delete text (either with keyboard or right-click | Cut). In Chrome and FF it does. Good work, Microsoft!

Answer (score 1):

As jQuery 1.7 you can use **bind(...)** and **unbind(...)** methods for attaching and removing respectively handlers.

Here are examples align your questuion:

```
$('#someElementId').bind('paste', function(){return false;});
```

- this one will block any attempts to paste from clipboard into element body. You can use also **cut**, **copy** and others as event types (see links bellow)

```
$('#someElementId').bind('copy', function(){return alert('Hey fella! Do not forget about copyrights!');});
```

So, in other cases, when you want to remove those handlers, you can use **unbind()** method:

```
$('#someElementId').unbind('copy');
```

Here some useful links:

- [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)
- [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)
- [full list of event types](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)