# jQuery validation - limit input to 3 specific lengths

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery as the validation tool for all of my forms and I have a request to limit the length of the inputs on one field to 8, 12, or 13 characters only.  Now, I'm already doing minlength: 8, and maxlength: 13 to take care of the upper and lower limits but haven't figured out how to limit the entry to exactly one of the three lengths.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075962/jquery-text-input-length-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a custom validation method.
Here is some rough code to get you started:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("specific_lengths", function(value, element, param) {
   if (this.optional(element)) return;

   for (var i = 0; i < param.length; i++){
       if (this.getLength($.trim(value), element) == param[i]) 
           return true;
   }

   return false;              
});
```

You could then hook up the validation like this:

```
jQuery("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    myField: {required: true,
              specific_lengths: [8, 12, 13]
             },
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!  (although I changed the last line of the custom validation to "});")

Comment: You're welcome! I just updated the answer with your correction - the code was written off-the-cuff so it was a bit raw :)