# keydown doesn't catch text-changed by hold-up copy action (Ctrl-V)

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have an text input.
I wanna limit number of its character downto 300.
So I'm catching keydown event on it.
But in case that user copies some text into clipboard, then pastes it into the text input by press and HOLD UP Ctrl-V (please be noticed that Ctrl-V is hold-up, not released), text is changed but I can't apply the limitation, TILL Ctrl-V is released
That's the fact though many ways have been tried : onkeydown, onkeypress, onkeyup, onchange.
Does anyone come up with solution ?
Thank you and have a good working day.

Comment: Have you tried using `maxLength` property on the input?

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075962/jquery-text-input-length-control

Comment: Note: you'll also have to allow for drag'n'drop into your input, but as Mrchief said if it is an `<input type="text">` you can just set the `maxLength` property (then you don't need any JS). If it's a `<textarea>` there's no `maxLength` so then you need to look into handling various events. Assuming this is for a field that gets submitted, don't forget to validate server-side too.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Thanks for mentioning server side validation. Important when JS is turned off.

Comment: I can't just simply set attribute maxLength of the input, because there're some more controls to show updated state/changes on the input control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (change your selector appropriately):

```
//Restrict text while pasting
$("#myinput").bind('paste', function () {
    var input = $(this);
    var maxLength = input.attr("maxLength");
    setTimeout(function () {
        input.val(input.val().substring(0, maxLength));
    }, 100);

});

//Restrict text while typing
$("#myinput").live("keypress", function () {
    var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxLength");
    return $(this).val().length <= maxLength - 1;
});
```

Comment: Would expanding your `paste` handler to cover `mouseup` too be enough to handle drag'n'drop?

Comment: Your suggestion works perfectly for me. I'm sorry I haven't get enough 15 reputation to vote for your extremely great answer. Anyway, thanks.