# jQuery - char counter doesn't work with paste event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I wrote a jQuery character counter, it works when I type, but not when text is pasted.
The function is executed upon paste, but count doesn't change. I am not sure if `val()` function is correct or really in synch with DOM. Any ideas?

```
 counter = function () {
     $j("strong#status-field-char-counter").text($j("#Panel1messagesmessage").val().length);
     alert('event');
 };


 $j("textarea").keyup(counter);
 $j("textarea").bind('paste', counter);
 $j("#Panel1messagesmessage").bind('copy', counter);
 $j("#Panel1messagesmessage").bind('delete', counter);
```

Comment: 'paste' is not listed as a valid event in http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind ... also, you can add events as the 2nd param of `bind()` as a string with each event separated by a space `$('#selector').bind('click mouseover', function(){} )`

Comment: Here's a SO question addressing unsupported events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237254/how-do-you-handle-oncut-oncopy-and-onpaste-in-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

textarea contents can be changed in a number of ways, instead of trying to catch them all, simply install a routine that checks the content every 0.5 second, like

```
$(function() {
   window.charCount = 0;
   setInterval(function() {
      var c = $("textarea").val().length;
      if(c != window.charCount) {
        window.charCount = c;
        $("span").html(window.charCount); 
      }
    }, 500);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually use `keyup` in combination with `change`

The `change` event fires when the textbox loses focus, but only if the value was modified since it received focus.

Comment: I did a try with `keydown`, but `keyup` seems to do the trick well, very much for _paste_ as well.

Answer (score 2):

Quick play about:

```js
$("#textarea").change(function() {
              $("#status-field-char-counter").text($("#textarea").val().length);
         }).keyup(function() {
          $("#status-field-char-counter").text($("#textarea").val().length);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="status-field-char-counter">here</p>
    <input id="textarea" type="text" />
```