# Intercept Paste data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboarddata

I got the following code from [Intercept paste event in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035071/intercept-paste-event-in-javascript).

I need to get it before it is pasted, otherwise i lose the "\n" characters i need to save.

It works great to intercept clipboard data for one element with an id. I need it to work on all input elements. When I try to use jQuery to get the input elements nothing.

Any help is appreciated.

```
var paster = function () {
    var myElement = document.getElementByTagName('pasteElement');
    myElement.onpaste = function(e) {
        var pastedText = undefined;
        if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE
            pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
        } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
            pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        }
        processExcel(pastedText); // Process and handle text...
        return false; // Prevent the default handler from running.
    };
}
```

Comment: there is no jquery in there. that's just plain javascript...

Comment: Correct. I'm willing to do it either way.

Comment: so show your jquery code. we are not here to bang out a solution for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add a `paste` event listener to the document.

```
document.addEventListener("paste", function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
    var pastedText = undefined;
    if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE
        pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
        pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.value = "You just pasted '" + pastedText + "'";
    return false;
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6SqS/)

Answer (score 3):

What [nmaier](http:///users/484441/nmaier) said, but you also need to check for the original event.

```
document.addEventListener("paste", function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
    var pastedText = undefined;
    if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE
        pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    } else {
        var clipboardData = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData;
        if (clipboardData && clipboardData.getData) {
            pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.value = "You just pasted '" + pastedText + "'";
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also, you should probably add the event listener just to the element, instead of the whole document.