# How to prevent a user from entering negative values in Html input

Tags: html

I am using the following html input element for collecting the product quantity in Html page but the user can still go ahead and manually enter negative value. For example: I selected the the textbox and entered -100 and input field took it without complaining about it.

How can I prevent user from entering 0 and non-negative values in Html input element?

```
<input type="number" id="qty" value="" size="3" min="1" />
```

Comment: Check for it and prompt the user or display an error. There are many ways to do this

Comment: Are there any new features in Html5 that actually does this ?

Comment: what you have is correct html5 and it should prevent negative values or zero... sadly not all the browsers support it http://caniuse.com/#search=number

Comment: You can take a look at http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-number.php for cross browser support, you would need some js

Comment: When you say the field took it, does that mean that you could unfocus the field and post the form? (Standard precaution applies: you need to validate the value on the server as well, since the entire form can be bypassed.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the `<input type="number">` still not being widely well supported, you are still better off using a text input. Preventively you could disallow any characters which are not numbers with the `keypress` event and `e.preventDefault()`. However be sure that if you want to support legacy browsers (IE8-), there are a [number of inconsistencies](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) to take into account regarding returned key codes/ char codes. If you also want to disallow pasting non-number content, you can do so with the `paste` event and `e.clipboardData.getData('plain/text')` (for a complete implementation see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035071/intercept-paste-event-in-javascript))

Test with the code below:

```js
var myInput = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
myInput.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  var key = !isNaN(e.charCode) ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
  function keyAllowed() {
    var keys = [8,9,13,16,17,18,19,20,27,46,48,49,50,
                51,52,53,54,55,56,57,91,92,93];
    if (key && keys.indexOf(key) === -1)
      return false;
    else
      return true;
  }
  if (!keyAllowed())
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);

// EDIT: Disallow pasting non-number content
myInput.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
  var pasteData = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  if (pasteData.match(/[^0-9]/))
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Don't forget an onblur check when data is pasted 

Comment: @Mouser thanks for pointing out, I forgot to test that. However because I was going for a 'preventive' approach, I went with the `paste` event to intercept the content before it is outputted.

Answer (score 6):

You can validate the value with regex with the `pattern` attribute:

```
<input type="number" pattern="^[1-9]\d*$" name="qty">
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in form validation `validity.valid`, user won't be able to enter or paste negative values. Also user won't be able enter decimals. More info [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-forms-javascript-constraint-validation-api/)

```
<input type="number" min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<input type="number" min="0">
```

Comment: This only works with using the arrows, users can still enter or copy and paste a negative number in