# In Jquery How to handle paste?

Tags: javascript, jquery, paste

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do you handle oncut, oncopy, and onpaste in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237254/how-do-you-handle-oncut-oncopy-and-onpaste-in-jquery)
>   [jQuery catch paste input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input)

I have a textarea, on paste to that textarea I want to

1. format pasting values
2. append to textarea

could that be done in Javascript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an onpaste event that works in modern day browsers:

```
$("#textareaid").bind("paste", function(){});
```

Problem with the event, it tells you that it is about to happen, but it doesn't give you what the user is pasting. JavaScript has restricted acccess to the clipboard and by default it is disabled. If the access is enabled you can [read the clipboard data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035071/intercept-paste-event-in-javascript) and than manipulate it.

Comment: Doesn't `e.target.value` give you what the user is pasting?

Comment: @jobmo Well a bit has changed in the 6 years that this was answered. You get what was pasted with event.clipboardData. Reading the value will get you the entire contents of the textarea.

Comment: `e.target.value` does not necessarily contain the value. You might need `setTimeout` https://stackoverflow.com/a/1503425/577052

Comment: `event.clipboardData` does not exist in IE11