# Any other alternative to capturing text on Ctrl+V

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to capture the text on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> event as below..

1. Creating a textarea in the page and setting height 0px and width 0px. like below

   ```
     <textarea id="a" style="height:0px;width:0px"></textarea>
   ```
2. On pressing V key i am setting the focus to that textarea and then using Ctrl+V button. Like below..

   ```
    shortcut.add("X",function() {
     $('#a').focus();
    });
    // In between user have to press Ctrl+V to paste the content
    shortcut.add("V",function() {
     alert($('#a').val());
    });
   ```

I think this as a most inefficient approach and waiting for valuable suggestions to improve this..

Comment: It's called google. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237254/how-do-you-handle-oncut-oncopy-and-onpaste-in-jquery and http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/cutcopypaste.html

Comment: There's no real alternative to this, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Consciousness: I don't think you've read the question properly: the OP wants to capture the text pasted, which is not generally possible using the paste event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach events to the `paste` event.

```
$('textarea').bind('paste', function() {
   // Hello, Mr. Paste!
});
```

Comment: On paste event I cannot capture the pasted text.. Like $(this).val() returns me null/previously pasted text.

Comment: You could update the string into a variable every time it's changed, and if it's a paste event compare the strings

Answer (score 0):

You can capture CTRL + V as :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var ctrlDown = false;
    var ctrlKey = 17, vKey = 86;

    $(document).keydown(function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) ctrlDown = true;
    }).keyup(function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) ctrlDown = false;
    });

    $("textarea").keydown(function(e)
    {
        if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == vKey)) return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I have shortcut.js file to capture Ctrl+V operation on the fly.. That is not my ploblem

Comment: Not the answer to this question but it answered mine. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8760097/388902