# Why doesn't my text box word counting code work when I paste text with the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, jquery-events, onkeyup

I am using jQuery for my application.

I have used Keyup and Change events combined on a function. i.e. I have a textbox and whenever I type in it the word counts comes on top of it. So basically I have word count function which works on `Keyup` and `Change` events.

The problem is when I use mouse to paste some text in text box the count doesn't changes unless I press some key or I click elsewhere.

Here is my code :

```
events :
'keyup #IdOfTextbox'  : 'wordCounter'
'change #IdOfTextbox'  : 'wordCounter'
wordCounter() : =>
//Code for counting words in Text Box
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you handle oncut, oncopy, and onpaste in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237254/how-do-you-handle-oncut-oncopy-and-onpaste-in-jquery)

Comment: You can try binding on the 'focus', and 'paste' events.

Comment: @c4urself seems like a good answer, you should post it as such!

Comment: @c4urself - thanks, but its not working i have to click atleast once outside the textbox to update the word count. I am trying to make it like they have in Twitter i.e Counts get change simply by pasting some words using mouse.

Comment: @Arpit The answer I gave, did work for me in Chrome and Firefox, which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").bind("paste keyup change", function() {
        console.log($(this).val().length);
    });
});
```