# Better way to inspect a input form with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, events, event-handling, onchange

I know that the most quick way to inspect a form can be `.keyup()` or `.keydown()` but what about if the user copy/pastes some text? Tha event will be missed but the content in the input might have changed.

Also if the user presses (or lets) e.g. the *alt* key that event will trigger the query (uselessly in my case).

Is there any similar event handler like "text change" but in real time inspection? Like `onchange` but as a handler.

Comment: You could use setInterval() method and test it every n miliseconds.

Comment: Do you want to monitor the change and format it on the way? If not then why not to pass the analysis on `blur()` instead?

Comment: @Grzegorz I want to monitor the change like the typeahead effect but more efficiently (without unnecessary key press but with copy/paste-from menu- option. I can't think any other possible changes on a text input)

Comment: Do it on all events, `change keyup focus blur` and that should work for everything even copy/paste. I did it like this in [my plugin](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/) and it works fine.

Comment: This is the absolute best way I've found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574941/best-way-to-track-onchange-as-you-type-in-input-type-text/574971

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.oneinput = function(callback) {        
        function testInput(){ 
            var tb = jQuery(this);
            var currentValue = tb.val();
            if (tb.data("lastInput") !== currentValue ) {
                tb.data("lastInput",currentValue );
                if(callback) { 
                    callback.call(this) 
                };
            }
            return this;
        }    
        $(this).bind("keyup input paste", testInput);
    };
}(jQuery));

$('input').oneinput( function(){ console.log(this.value); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always check if the user is copy / pasting text using the bind() JQuery method. There's a similar question on Stack Overflow that can be found here: [How do you handle oncut, oncopy, and onpaste in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237254/how-do-you-handle-oncut-oncopy-and-onpaste-in-jquery)