# How to limit characters on mouse paste event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you handle oncut, oncopy, and onpaste in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237254/how-do-you-handle-oncut-oncopy-and-onpaste-in-jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Description').bind('keyup', function() {   
        var characterLimit = 350;
        var charactersUsed = $(this).val().length;
        if (charactersUsed > characterLimit) {
            charactersUsed = characterLimit;
            $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, characterLimit));
            $(this).scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qCasN/

This is my code. I am trying to paste some content in description box using mouse right click paste, but it is not handled by the code. I don't know where it goes wrong, can anybody help on fixing this for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Erm... can't you just use `maxlength` attribute here?

Comment: keyUp is not mouseUp - also I fixed your brackets

Answer (score 0):

You should use `change` or `input` events instead of `keyup`. If you don't mind little performance loss you could do:

```
$('#Description').bind('keyup change input', function () { .. });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3HdAd/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `mouseup` event, instead of the `keyup` event. `keyup` is for keyboard actions.
I am not sure if the page will receive a `mouseup` event from a context menu, though. (right-click -> "paste" makes you click a "paste" button on a non-DOM element.

---

Or the events Miszy suggested would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onpaste event to handle this :-

```
$("#Description").bind("paste", function(){} );
```

check this link :- [How do you handle oncut, oncopy, and onpaste in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237254/how-do-you-handle-oncut-oncopy-and-onpaste-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the default jquery keyup event like below:

```
var characterLimit = 360; 
$("#Description").keyup(function(){
  if($("#Description").val().length > characterLimit){
    $("#Description").val($("#Description").val().substring(0,characterLimit));
   }
});
```

or you can use keydown event as

```
var characterLimit = 360; 
    $("#Description").keydown(function(){
      if($("#Description").val().length > characterLimit){
        return false;
       }
    });
```