# Using a change event for text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I am using a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/ablanco/jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap) that provides rulesets for visually displaying the quality of a user's typed in password.

This is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mmXV5/563/) to see how that plugin works.

This is working fine for me. But I have a question, when I am typing a password the visual progress bar is working. but when I paste some text to `password` field its progress bar is not working.

can any body tell me, can we update this plugin to fix this issue.

I use this jQuery  -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        onLoad: function () {
            $('#messages').text('Start typing password');
        },
        onKeyUp: function (evt) {
            $(evt.target).pwstrength("outputErrorList");
        }
    };
    $(':password').pwstrength(options);
});
```

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237254/how-do-you-handle-oncut-oncopy-and-onpaste-in-jquery

Comment: [Detect all changes to a <input type=“text”> (immediately) using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [the plugin documentation](https://github.com/ablanco/jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap#methods), you can force an update using `.pwstrength("forceUpdate")`.

Just add an event listeners for the `paste`/`change` events, then update the password's strength using the method.

```
$(':password').on('paste change', function () {
    $(this).pwstrength("forceUpdate");
});
```

If you want to update the password's strength when programically changing the password (i.e., clearing it), all you would have to do is trigger a change event on the input element. For example:

```
$('#clear').on('click', function () {
    $('#password').val('').change();
});
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/c25LxL9x/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is working when I paste something into my password field. But when I insert some text into my password field click on a button then this progress bar not working..

Comment: like this - `if (linkId == 'generate'){ $('#password').val(password);
      $('#random').empty(); `

Comment: I am using a password generator. when an user generated a password there is a button named 'use password' when clicking this button the generated password must display on my password field. all these are working for me.

Comment: when inserting this generated password to my password field this progress bar is not working.

Comment: But when pasting some text as password into my password field this progress bar is working. So Josh Crozier, can you understand what I said?

Comment: This is not dear.. Can we chat regarding this?

Comment: @TNK We are talking. It's still unclear what you're asking, though. Do you mind preparing an example demonstrating what you are having trouble with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68623/discussion-between-tnk-and-josh-crozier).